# Do I need to run Boost's configure script to build libraries (e.g. graph, test)?

Tags: configuration, boost

If I don't want to install Boost but I want to build one of the libraries (i.e. BGL, for using graphml) is there a way to build the library in a system independent manner without running *.configure*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: it depends.

I'd just try to copy the relevant sources to your project and build them. Boost is fairly good at supporting that sort of thing, as it doesn't rely too much on configure, but rather on compiler-/platform-specific defines to sort out which platform it's being built on.

I suspect that something like BGL would even be a better candidate, while highly platform-dependent code like the threading code wouldn't work as well. Having said that, I know at least one project that successfully copies boost's threading code and spirit into it's own repository, and it works like a charm.

I'd just give it a try and see what happens.